# How can I wrap into a wrapper this JSON builded by a Spring MVC controller method?

Tags: json, spring-mvc

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and this is my first time that I am producing a JSON.

So I have the following situation:

I have this 2 model classes:

1) **CountryData**:

```
public class CountryData {

    private String label;
    private String subdataConcat;

    private ArrayList<CountryDataChild>  countryDataChildList;

    public CountryData(String label, String subdataConcat, ArrayList<CountryDataChild> countryDataChildList) {
        super();
        this.label = label;
        this.subdataConcat = subdataConcat;
        this.countryDataChildList = countryDataChildList;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getSubdataConcat() {
        return subdataConcat;
    }

    public void setSubdataConcat(String subdataConcat) {
        this.subdataConcat = subdataConcat;
    }

    public ArrayList<CountryDataChild> getCountryDataChildList() {
        return countryDataChildList;
    }

    public void setCountryDataChildList(ArrayList<CountryDataChild> countryDataChildList) {
        this.countryDataChildList = countryDataChildList;
    }

}
```

2) **CountryDataChild**:

```
public class CountryDataChild {

    private String label;
    private String code;

    public CountryDataChild(String label, String code) {
        super();
        this.label = label;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

}
```

Finally into a controller class I have this controller method that generate a JSON containing the **CountryData** information:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getCountryData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody CountryData getShopInJSON() {

    ArrayList<CountryDataChild> countryDataChildList = new ArrayList<CountryDataChild>();

    CountryDataChild child1 = new CountryDataChild("Lazio", "lazio");
    CountryDataChild child2 = new CountryDataChild("Lombardia", "lombardia");

    countryDataChildList.add(child1);
    countryDataChildList.add(child2);

    CountryData countryData = new CountryData("Italia", "y", countryDataChildList);

    return countryData;

}
```

This works pretty fine and, when it is performed, generate this **JSON** as output into my browser:

```
{"label":"Italia","subdataConcat":"y","countryDataChildList":[{"label":"Lazio","code":"lazio"},{"label":"Lombardia","code":"lombardia"}]}
```

Ok, the only problem is that according to the provided specification this object have to be:

```
 countrydata({"label":"Italia","subdataConcat":"y","countryDataChildList":[{"label":"Lazio","code":"lazio"},{"label":"Lombardia","code":"lombardia"}]})
```

So basically the generated JSON have to be wrapped inside the **countrydata(...)**

How can I implement this specification? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to generate JSONP rather than normal JSON. One way to do that with Spring MVC is to leave your `Controller` as-is and then create a filter as described here: https://patrickgrimard.com/2010/07/28/tutorial-implementing-a-servlet-filter-for-jsonp-callback-with-springs-delegatingfilterproxy/

That is where you would wrap your JSON in the `countrydata` function and also set the content type to `text/javascript`.